# Adding A search bar to google maps places

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-places-api

I am looking to add a search bar to my google maps. I need the search bar to only find hotels. Is there a way I can do this? Current JS below.

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 3,
        center: {
            lat: 46.619261,
            lng: -33.134766
        }
    });

    var labels = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    var locations = [
        { lat: 40.785091, lng: -73.968285 },
        { lat: 41.084045, lng: -73.874245 },
        { lat: 40.754932, lng: -73.984016 }
    ];

    var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
        return new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            label: labels[i % labels.length]
        });
    });

    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, { imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m' });
}
```

Comment: You mean like in this example? https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-hotelsearch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to filter out the predictions returned by the Places API Autocomplete service to hotels or lodging only.

But, we do have an existing feature request for this in our Google Issue Tracker. To express your interest and to subscribe you to its latest updates, I suggest that you star this entry: https://issuetracker.google.com/35820774

In the mean time, you may want to check out this [sample](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-hotelsearch) which uses [Autocomplete service](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete) that's filtered to only return results that match `locality` or `administrative_area_level_3` by using `types: ['(cities)']`

After selecting a city, it will look for all nearby hotels in the selected city, within the viewport of the map using the [Nearby search service](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests) that's filtered to `types: ['lodging']`.

```
var search = {
    bounds: map.getBounds(),
    types: ['lodging']
};
```